# Oracle SQL: Update a cache table with current data

Tags: oracle, caching, merge

I'm sorry.  This HAS to have been asked a million times, but my Googlefu is weak.  Could someone please point me to a good answer?

Oracle 11g, being invoked from Perl.  We have a slow query.  It has been optimized by periodically getting all the possible results and caching them into a table.  This has been implemented by (crude pseudocode)

```
muchdata = ResultsOfQuery(...)
DELETE FROM cachetable
foreach row in muchdata
    INSERT INTO cachetable (col1, col2, ..., coln) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)
```

I've been tasked with refactoring it to improve performance (and the above also nukes the auditing).  I think that the data rarely change, but the tasker is probably expecting to see INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE in the resulting code.  Oh, and there are no primary keys.

It looks to me like the MERGE statement is much of the way there, along the lines of "MERGE INTO cachetable using (select ?, ?, ..., ? FROM DUAL) newdata ...".  But that can handle inserts and updates, but I don't see how it can directly do deletes.  But [Oracle SQL “deep update”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918206/oracle-sql-deep-update) has a technique that I don't understand yet and that may not be convenient because there's no primary key.

Or, given that I think the data rarely changes, maybe I should simply do

```
muchdata = ResultsOfQuery(...)
muchdatafromdb = SELECT * FROM cachetable
if (muchdata is not the same as muchdatafromdb)
    DELETE FROM cachetable
    foreach row in muchdata
        INSERT INTO cachetable (col1, col2, ..., coln) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to figure out what is wrong with your slow query, and fix that.  Saying you have a "slow query" without any supporting detail  makes it difficult to diagnose.  Maybe you are trying to fix the wrong problem.

Comment: Certainly making the original query fast would have been great, but another coder looked at the whole system for days and could find no better solution than to cache the results.  The original query involves half a dozen tables, subselects, and a recursive select.  (Yeah, restructuring the tables involved is on the todo list -- but at the moment the architecture is what it is.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for a materialized view, would that be an option? Can `ResultsOfQuery` be formultated as a SQL query?

Comment: I will look into it.  But I am still curious about whether there's a good answer to the original problem: given a table being used as a cache, is there a good efficient way to update it?

Comment: I checked.  Looks like we can't do it -- there are run-time configuration parameters that affect the results.

Comment: Runtime configuration parameters wouldn't put me off. You want to precompute the query, at this point in time the parameters need to be known. I'd put it in a config table, which is part of the mview query. Will be very, very fast...

Comment: Failing that, the second best option is to precompute the full query on a second table and transfer the changes to your original table by `MERGE` and `DELETE` (basically a poor man's mview)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the suggestions.

It appears that I was correct, that there are few changes from run to run.  Due to circumstances, unfortunately, restructuring the tables or altering the database schema were not feasible.  I'll mention the materialized view with materialized log to the main developer when he's available -- that looks like the best solution in the intermediate term.

I eventually did my own merge / materialized view in code in the crude and obvious way, which got a large performance gain and will get us through the next few weeks.

(The crude and obvious way:
 - SELECT * from existing table to get the old values
 - Call the function to get the new values
 - Use hash tables to index them by a likely key
 - The deletes are old minus new
 - The inserts are new minus old
Of course it's crude.  It didn't take much time to code, no time to debug, and see "large performance gain" and "get us through the next few weeks", supra.)